# Android Studio keeps synchronizing files

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio keeps saying it's synchronizing files (indicated on the bottom left corner of the IDE as shown in the image

[image].

Meanwhile, certain functions are not working at this time. For example, variables and functions are not highlighted in the code, hence I can not see at which locations in my code that a variable/function appears. This really makes coding very difficult.

Anyone know what Android Studio is synchronizing? And how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick is disabling version control in Android Studio.

Try:

File->Settings->Version Control-> unregister Git root